# Compass is not working in android

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximitysensor, digital-compass

I have following this tutorial for android compass. [Android Compass Code Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-compass-code-example.html).But when i run this on my Micromax Funbook tablet and also run on Sony experia tipo phone but nothing happen on compass only it's display compass image. So what is the problem of these? If these devices not supported then how to make this app for those devices?

Comment: Are you sure your devices supports this functionality? For my devices compass works on glaxy s3 and do not works on htc one v

Comment: I don't know. but i run on sony xperia zr mobile it's work perfectly. but it's not run in xperia tipo mobile. @SergeyPekar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your devices does not support (does not have needed sensors) compass.

I have compass app on google play and as you can see on the screenshots your devices does not support compass. So It is impossible to make it work.

Here screenshots with unsupported devices list for compass app from google play:

[image]
[image]